# Should we delete a pointer that is not new/malloc by us?

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(ClassB *p) b(p){}
    ~ClassA(){delete b;}
    ClassB *b;
};
```

Is this kind of design a good one?

Comment: never ever except the situation the `ClassA` is taking ownership over this `ClassB` instance, which is given by the `*p` pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this is a bad idea. Quite often you just don't know how the object of ClassB was created. It could be a pointer to element of an array created with the new[] operator, or it could be handed to you from separate dll which uses custom memory allocator. In those cases using operator delete to delete this pointer would be a serious error.

Comment: And usually, users of this api just use a ClassB* parameter, it may be created by new, or just the address of a ClassB element. In the later case, it will lead to double free.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is *it depends*. You have to make clear who is responsible for the object lifetime.

Also `ClassA` lacks a user-defined copy-constructor and assignment operator and this can lead to undefined behavior. For example:

```
ClassA object1( new ClassB() ); //object1 takes ownership of the object
ClassA object2( object1 ); //object2 takes ownership of the same object
// now first object2 is destroyed and deletes the object
// then object1 is destroyed and double-delete happens
```

so your example is likely not a very good one.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

> ```
> class ClassA  { 
>   ClassB *b;  
> public: 
>   ClassA(ClassB * p) {b = p;} 
>   ~ClassA() {delete b;}  
> };
> ```

This is not good design. The one who creates should be the one who deletes.

Answer (score 1):

Usually using pointers in this kind of situation is bad design. In this kind of situation smart pointers are your best friends. However if you have to use pointers then just choose either way and carefully document it

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything wrong with this specifically - technically you have passed ownership to of the ClassB instead to the ClassA instance when created (i.e. a ClassB instance exists before ClassA was needed, but once ClassA is created it becomes the owner of a ClassB).

Whether or not it is a good design depends on the context in which it is applied.  For example, does it make sense that ClassA takes ownership of a ClassB? Should you be using a smart pointer instead of a "plain old" pointer?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it's preferable to avoid this situation by using smart pointers or by deleting an object at the same level it was created... or by not using pointers at all.

At the same time, I wouldn't say it's necessarily bad design to transfer object ownership, as long as you make it obvious to ClassA users in documentation. I've encountered a similar situation when writing functions which take a pointer to an object and copy-construct it for their own use. Where needed, I tend to annotate these functions with "parameter copy semantics" or something which tells the caller "You can do what you want with this object after I return... I have my own copy".

If you're using raw pointers, I'd consider it important to establish these sorts of caller contracts.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, no, this is a confusing/inconsistent design (you normally want corresponding `new` and `delete` to occur at the same level).  However, there are some exceptions; for instance, smart pointers are provided with a raw pointer and then take ownership of the object, so they are responsible for invoking `delete` when it is no longer needed.